# I need a faster way to highlight text in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#

I have this project to highlight the common statements in two files.
So I read each of them in RichTextBox and find the common statements and put them into a string, named `output` here.
Now what I need is a faster way to highlight only the common statements in both RichTextBoxes.

Here is my code:

```
string[] splitted = output.Split('.');

int index1;

for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
{
   index1 = 0;
   while (index1 < rtb1.Text.LastIndexOf(splitted[i]) + 1)
   {
      rtb1.Find(splitted[i], index1, rtb1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
      rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
      index1 = rtb1.Text.IndexOf(splitted[i], index1) + 1;
   }
}

for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
{
   index1 = 0;
   while (index1 < rtb2.Text.LastIndexOf(splitted[i]) + 1)
   {
      rtb2.Find(splitted[i], index1, rtb2.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
      rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
      index1 = rtb.Text.IndexOf(splitted[i], index1) + 1;
   }
}
```

Where `rtb1` and `rtb2` are the RichTextBoxes.
I got the highlighting code from another thread here. Now what I believe that this code takes O(N^3) or even more.
I need to optimize it to O(N^2) at most. I'd appreciate any Help.

Edit:
I also tried using `Regex.Matches`:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(output, RegexOptions.Compiled);
MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(rtb1.Text);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   rtb1.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
   rtb1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

When `rtb1` contains:

> [1] INVESTIGATING THE IMPACT OF THE YEAR 2000 PROBLEM  The Year 2000 (Y2K) technology problem started as an innocuous short-term solution to the oppressively high cost of computer memory in the 1950s and 1960s. 
>   [2] Programmers expected that the problems created by the limited, two-digit method of date storage would solve themselves as companies, governments and other computer-owners updated their hardware and software. 
>   [3] Fifty years after the introduction of the computer, the Y2K problem has the potential to develop into a worldwide crisis.

And `rtb2` contains:

> [1] INVESTIGATING THE IMPACT OF THE YEAR 2000 PROBLEM  The Year 2000 (Y2K) technology problem started as an innocuous short-term solution to the oppressively high cost of computer memory in the 1950s and 1960s. 
>   [3] Fifty years after the introduction of the computer, the Y2K problem has the potential to develop into a worldwide crisis.

`output` should contain:

> [1] INVESTIGATING THE IMPACT OF THE YEAR 2000 PROBLEM  The Year 2000 (Y2K) technology problem started as an innocuous short-term solution to the oppressively high cost of computer memory in the 1950s and 1960s. 
>   [3] Fifty years after the introduction of the computer, the Y2K problem has the potential to develop into a worldwide crisis.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185514/discussion-on-question-by-maher-farghaly-i-need-a-faster-way-to-highlight-text-i).